# trouble putting it all together in JAVA

Tags: java

I am currently taking intro to JAVA. I am having trouble putting everything I am learning together to complete my assignments. When I read my assignments for class half the time I don't even know where to start but I feel like I am understanding the materiel. I don't know if I am just over thinking it but it is starting to frustrate me a lot. For example I completed one of my assignments and then google it to see if I was right even though it complied and ran. The one I found had more lines of code then me and I wasn't sure if I left something out or why they had more code.

Do you guys know of any resources I can use to help me understand how everything works together I guess. I read my text book, search youtube, and read the fourm. I am just having a hard time picturing the program before I start.

I don't know if this is normal or not and any help would be great....

thanks guys

Comment: Watch the Java videos at https://thenewboston.com/. I recommend it to all my students.

Comment: People write code differently, don't judge your progress on how to write your code based on others if you are using correct syntax. I've created programs that were two times shorter than fellow classmates and both ran equally the same. Judge your code based on output, and if you continue programming you will get the overall concept behind programming. On another topic, this question is extremely broad and shouldn't be asked on StackOverflow, try a forum or another section on StackExchange.

Comment: Thank's for the help guys.

Comment: Thank's for the help guys. @nicomp I use newboston's videos a lot and they help. I am just having trouble picturing how all of the different things work together I guess. I took programming logic and design and received an A. I felt I had a good understanding of the concepts. Would you guys know of any youtube videos of a large project start to finish so I could code along and picture how everything fits together. I have tried looking but I am not sure what would help best. Riley I have been told not to compare code but I think I am just over thinking it but it. I really do appreciate it

Comment: @X4flight ok, I'll tell you the next thing I tell all my students. ***write code***. ProjectEuler.net, TopCoder.com, codingbat.com, etc. I don't know your idea of a 'large project' but if you want to collaborate on something, create a GitHub account and let me know.

Comment: I appreciate the help guys. I found what I was looking for which ended up being on Oracle's website. The Java Documentation list everything out. Where I was having trouble was my text book was teaching something but it didn't show every method for enough detail and I was having trouble understanding it and see how to apply it, I guess. Now that I came across the Documentation page I am working through everything a lot smoother.